# Executing grep in perl always returns and empty string

Tags: perl, grep

When I run grep from my command line in CentOS 5.8 using the following command I get

```
grep -E "APPLIANCE=\"VPMX\"" /filepath/appliance_data.sh
```

with the results of

```
APPLIANCE="VPMX"; export APPLIANCE
```

When I run the following commands perl

```
$out = `grep -E "APPLIANCE=\"VPMX\"" /filepath/appliance_data.sh`;
`echo "Output grep TV: $out" >> /tmp/debug`;
```

the $out variable is always an empty string

How do I get the same output as the command line grep?

I have tried quiet grep using the -q parameter, and have also tried the command with < /dev/null with no change in the result.

Comment: Tip: `print qq\`...\`;` will show the command you executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes as [backticks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) work like a double quoted string by default:

```
$out = `grep -E "APPLIANCE=\\"VPMX\\"" /filepath/appliance_data.sh`;
```

Alternatively, you could the single quoted form of [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html):

```
$out = qx'grep -E "APPLIANCE=\"VPMX\"" /filepath/appliance_data.sh';
```

Comment: Or even replace his outer double-quotes as single-quotes: `'APPLIANCE="VPMX"'`